# Access method of a object declared through interface in another class by java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, interface

In my code below I get the printer1 type as interface(IPrinter) type but i actually want it as printer class type.

In JavaReflectionTrial.accessPrinter() i have 2 give the Slot as parameter not the printer

is it possible to get printer in JavaReflectionTrial as Printer object.

```
interface IPrinter {
  void enable();
}

class Printer implements Iprinter {
  void enable() {
  //doSomething;
  }
}

class Slot {
  public IPrinter printer1 = new Printer();
}

class JavaReflectionTrial {
  accessPrinter(Slot slot) {
    class cls=slot.getclass();
    field[] fields=cls.getfields();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `Slot` object and through reflection you want to get at its `printer1` member variable, you should be able to do that like this:

```
Class<?> cls = slot.getClass();
Field field = cls.getDeclaredField("printer1");

// Get the value of the printer1 member variable in slot
Printer printer = (Printer)field.get(slot);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the printer-field in the Slot is public, you should be able to get the instance in a normal way. (slot.printer1)

Comment: actually i want 2 access printer in runtime so only i m using reflection